# Joomla alert message title change

Tags: joomla, alert, message

I will change joomla java alert message [see this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnIM9.jpg)

But i dont come forwad...

My joomla is version 3 and this is on module mod_s5_quick_contact

thanks...

Comment: have you checked the module settings?

Comment: yes but there is no option

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the title then I suggest to do a language override as described here https://docs.joomla.org/J3.x:Language_Overrides_in_Joomla. If you want to alter the output at all, then do a template override of the module.